# rails 3 application before_filter with redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

my rails 3 apps need a before_filter for check if user are logged or not. if logged, redirect to subdomain. I use Devise for log system. After sign_up the user are redirect to his subdomain, but if he come back to the website and are logged again, he must be redirected to his subdomain again.

I tried this :

```
if current_user.present?
company_id = current_user.company_id
@company = Company.find(company_id)
redirect_to @company.subdomain + "." + request.domain
end
```

with this code, the url are : www.mywebsite.comsubdomain.mywebsite.com
Yeah, i think it's because redirect_to are for webpage not for new url.

I tried with

```
if current_user.present?
company_id = current_user.company_id
@company = Company.find(company_id)
root_url(:host => @company.subdomain + "." + request.domain)
end
```

but same thing. i get the same url as previous tests.

what can i do to redirect to my subdomain?

Answer (score 2):

This answer in another stackoverflow question should be your answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/327154/346693

What that answer provided:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_uri

  def check_uri
    redirect_to request.protocol + "www." + request.host_with_port + request.request_uri if !/^www/.match(request.host)
  end
end
```

The problem of your way is you are not providing a full url (http://sth.com vs sth.com)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example: [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501250/rails-calling-devise-authenticate-user-and-handling-invalid-user-password-exce).

You can use this as a starting place. Basically you would wrap the call to authenticate_user! inside your own before handler and if authenticate_user! raises an exception you can do your redirect.

If it doesn't raise the exception you can redirect somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exaclty what i'm looking for. This link are for page require user authorization to show content. If not logged, show the sign in page. What i need is only a way to detect if user are looged and if yes redirect to his subdomain, if not show content page normally at www.mydomain.com

Comment: authenticate_user! raises an exception if you're not logged in. passes if you are logged in.

Comment: Ok, thanks i will try this, i add this to my application_controller before_filter? thanks.

Comment: yeah, I'd write a custom before filter and then do the conditional redirect based upon calling authenticate_user! in it. In a more standard case I'd just use the authenticate_user! as the before_filter itself. Let me know if you run into roadblocks and I'd be glad to try and help with them.